# SQL Identity column if no input value in insert query in ADO.NET throws exception that it can't be null

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, identity-column

I have an identity column in the DB which is primary key and increments its value by itself. But I have a insert query in asp.net ado.net class like below:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(Name,[Image]) VALUES ('Nature',@img)", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, it throws me exception that it cannot be null.

My idea/goal is, I just want to insert the above two values only and the primary key column should increment by itself internally in DB. I have configured that in DB. However I don't know how to handle this error or tweak this code. Please help

Comment: please make sure that identity is enabled on your primary key column if it is Sql Server on the Image Table. Enabling identity will make it  as autonumber

Comment: @HatSoft: Ok, but I try without identity now. Well the following line throws exception --- cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text.ToString()); ---- The textbox3 has some value which is int I enter. It says conversion fails :( Any help please

Comment: Are you certain it's the ID column that the error is referring to?  That doesn't fit with the claim that you have it auto-numbering.

Comment: I would also rename `TextBox1` and `TextBox3` to represent the value that they hold (e.g. `txtID` and `txtName`).  That will reduce the number of errors you get mapping text boxes to parameters.

Comment: @DStanley: Well no no its doing perfect now. Actually in the insert query, I mistakenly used '@Name' instead of @@Name. Thank you Stanley :) Cheers

Comment: @Divine so is the code fixed for you or do you still have errors, if yes please can you post the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `ID` column on your `Images` table is an identity column.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Images(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Image] [image] NOT NULL)
```

If it is, then step through your code and make sure the parameters you are using are not null;  `TextBox1.Text` and `img`.

Lastly, make sure there are no other non-nullable columns on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you havn't provided the @Name parameter I your query and but you are sending values in your paramters.

**Please remove the 'Nature' value and type @Name.**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(Name,[Image]) VALUES (@Name ,@img)", conn); cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```