# Creating an auto increment

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I need to create an auto increment for an sql tabel programmatically.
I've tried this but it doesnt increment, just stays forever 1:

```
int i = 0;
i++;
```

What I'm doing wrong? If you want to see my sql insert code feel free to ask.

UPDATE

I found this on internet but its not working. Any help would be apreciated.

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE UXFaturas(IDNumFaturas int AUTO_INCREMENT, NumFaturas nchar(75),Cliente nchar(150), Valor int, "/*Estado nchar(50),*/ + "Data date, PRIMARY KEY (IDNumFaturas));", conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: why are you re inventing something sql can do for you?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ what do you mean by  re inventing?

Comment: Without any context I can't be sure but I'd say you have a scoping issue where you re-declare `i` every time you want to use it. But why don't you use the database feature for auto-increment?

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo - You can just make a column an autoincrementing primary key. You don't need (and probably shouldn't use) c# to do this.

Comment: @Crowcoder is it possible to use it with c#?

Comment: "What I'm doing wrong? " at least nothing in your out of any context posted code.

Comment: @MongZhu I can add more code if you wish

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo if by "it" you mean the database built-in feature for auto-increment then yes, you can.

Comment: @DangerZone I understand it should be easier doing it manually but I have to do it with c#

Comment: @Crowcoder I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo I would recommend using the default auto increment. What about using a GUID if you do need to insert the key from C#?

Comment: @Xela thanks for the suggestion, i'll keep that in mind

Comment: @Xela, depending on the DBMS, guids are not good if they are a primary key, unless you take care to make them sequential per the database engine's way of recognizing sequentiality (is that a word?). Document/NoSql dbs are the exception.

Comment: I've tried manually adding a primary key and now i cant add programmatically the data

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo if you use an auto-increment column (what database are you using? add it's tag to your question) then you do not include that column in an `INSERT` query, the database handles it "auto"matically.

Comment: @Crowcoder I added the database i'm using into tags as you sugested.

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo that is not a specific database, it is a general tag for structured query language. Are you using Microsoft Sql Server? MySql? You should also add your code that executes the database command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Identity column if no input value in insert query in ADO.NET throws exception that it can't be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112467/sql-identity-column-if-no-input-value-in-insert-query-in-ado-net-throws-exceptio)

Comment: @Crowcoder I remored the column in the insert of the primary key and still doesnt insert

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry I miss understood. I'll fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IDENTITY` which will auto-increment and never duplicate. Notice you don't insert anything into this column... SQL Server handles that for you.

```
declare @table table (i int identity(1,1), x varchar(2), z int null)
insert into @table
values
('A',null),
('B',null),
('C',null),
('D',null),
('E',null)

select * from @table
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @JosueFigueiredo this is standard practice. You should never increment with i++ or anything similar in SQL. It's set-based and i++ means you are using a loop which are performance killers in this language. It's why the identity property exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple, if you want to generate an id programaticaly you need to search for the highest id in your table and affect to your `i` variable and then do `i++;` because with your code right now 0 is always the value of i and since its a local variable there is no way for it to increment correctly.

Note: it probably isen't a good idea to do it by programmation since you can just use the built-in feature of a primary-key and I can't very well see a good reason that requires you to generate it manually

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: It is never good to recommend implementing auto increment like that. Race conditions abound.

Comment: @Crowcoder like i said in the note it isen't a very good  idea but I still gave him the information if he needs it

Comment: Like you said after my vote and comment? I'll take the downvote away but it's still not what I consider an upvote.

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry its my fault I didn't make the note sooner I realized it could be understood that way after your comment , so ill try to be clearer next time thanks for the heads up